# How to work with desqueezed anamorphic footage in FCPX

Tags: editing, formats, fcpx, setup

I have footage from an Array Alexa Mini, shot with anamorphic lenses. The footage was desqueezed in camera, so the resulting video resolution is `2944x2160`. The codec is `Timecode, Apple ProRes 4444`, and the color profile is `HD(1-1-1)`

2944x1260 does not appear to be a standard format and I'm unsure how I should be working with these clips in FCPX.

I also need to sync up audio and video. When I try to synchronise clips, the automatic settings are:

1. 720p HD 1280x720
2. Rec 709
3. automatic Audio Properties

Which seems too low a resolution to me. When I look at the options in custom settings, there is no format that matches the resolution of the source video.

So my question is, what setting should I be using for my synchronised clips and project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new library and then click on 'New Project'. Here you can change the format to any resolution you want.

[image: Custom Video Format]

In the sync dialogue your can also set a custom video format.

[image: Custom Video Format Sync Clips]